# Covariant derivative of a section of a trivial(?) associated bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

First I'll briefly outline the physical context in which my question arose:
If one tries to do 2D quantum mechanics in polar coordinates one encounters a problem with a property of the covariant derivative $\nabla$. Namely that the the radial momentum operator $P_r$ defined in terms of it $P_r:=-i\nabla_r=-i\partial_r$ (if the object to be derivated is a function $f:\mathbb{R^2}→ \mathbb{C}$) is no longer self adjoint. According to this lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C93KzJ7-Es4&t=1630s one can address this issue by interpreting the wave function $\Psi$ (i.e. the object to be derivated) no longer as a function $f_\Psi:\mathbb{R^2}→ \mathbb{C}$ but as a section $\Psi:\mathbb{R^2}→E$ on a $\mathbb{C}$-line bundle $E$ over $\mathbb{R^2}$. It is claimed that $E$ is also an associated fibre bundle to the frame bundle $L\mathbb{R^2}$ over $\mathbb{R^2}$ which can be equipped with a connection $\omega$. And for such $\Psi \in \Gamma(E)$ the covariant derivative contains an expression with $\omega$ which can be adjustet to get a $P_r=-i\nabla_r$ which is again self adjoint.

Now my problem with the argumentation: The frame bundle $L\mathbb{R^2}$ is trivial as one can easily find a global section of it. Every associated vector bundle of a trivial principal bundle is trivial too. But if $E$ is trivial a section $\Psi$ can be understood as a function $f_\Psi:\mathbb{R^2}→\mathbb{C}$, which is the starting point. The covariant derivative of such an object is of course again $\nabla_r=\partial_r$. My question now is: What is wrong in my derivation of a $\nabla_r$ for the section $\Psi$? Because I don't think my formula is valid and we just choose the one where a term with $\omega$ arises.

Comment: It is true that your bundle will be trivial, but that does not mean we have to equip it with the trivial connection (which amounts to simply taking partial derivatives). This is probably what the lecturer is trying to get at. The point of view that $\Psi$ is actually a section of an (a priori non-trivial) bundle helps to motivate a different choice of connection.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. What's still bothering me a bit is that it's still true that a section of a trivial bundle can be understood as a function $f_\Psi:\mathbb{R^2}→\mathbb{C}$. In this way it's still possible to define a covariant derivative of $\Psi$ which is just the partial derivative even though the Principal bundle may has a non-trvial $\omega$. I think there are 2 options: 1: the Isomorphism $\Psi→f_\Psi$ doesn't hold any longer (if $\omega$ is non trivial). 2: Both definitions of $\nabla$ are valid but we choose the one which works for our purposes. Which one is it?